# Mysql - Find paragraph (§) symbol

Tags: mysql, linux

I want to perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM holidays WHERE name LIKE '% (§)';
```

It works as expected on Windows, but it won't return anything on Linux. (This is the only known difference between both mariaDB servers)

How do I get this to work on the server running linux?

I use mysql, both databases contain the same data and use InnoDB. If provided data is not sufficient to solve this Problem, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are seeing this problem but have you tried `WHERE RIGHT(NAME, 4) = ' (§)'` instead of the `like`?

Comment: @Fred tried it with `RIGHT(name, 4) = ' (§)'` but that didn't do it. Can I maybe somehow escape that symbol?

Comment: I don't know Linux at all but have you tried comparing ASCII values instead?    `WHERE ASCII(SUBSTRING(name, LEN(name)-1,1)) = 167`.  There may well be a better way to do this but I don't know Linux and this works fine in SQL on Windows.

Comment: @Fred Thank you, comparing these worked. I had to change it to `ASCII(SUBSTRING(name, LENGTH(name)-1,1))` and see if the value equaled **41 or 167**. I got no idea why the value differ though. If you post your comment as an answer I would accept it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Linux at all but have you tried comparing ASCII values instead?

For example:

```
WHERE ASCII(SUBSTRING(name, LEN(name)-1,1)) = 167.
```

There may well be a better way to do this but I don't know Linux and this works fine in SQL on Windows